# Java JNLP webstart setting the tooltip for my application icon

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to change the tooltip for the JavaWebStart Application.

According to the documentation, we can add **description** tag in Jnlp file and it will change the tooltip, but that is not working for me.

This is what i have added in Jnlp file for tooltip.

```
<information>
          <description>FCC</description>
        <description kind="tooltip">FCC JET</description>
</information>
```

As you can see in image, the tooltip is showing java. I want to change that.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: `description`s will be available to the user through the Web Start launcher, and not as a desktop icon tooltip. did you try `title`

Comment: i tried title as well. I didn't work either.